# How to configure pgAdmin on Debian/Apache server

Tags: postgresql, apache, debian, pgadmin

I have installed PostgreSQL DB on my Debian/Apache server. I have also local pgAdmin client running and I can connect to my DB, everything is ok.

What I need is configuring pgAdmin on my server for the web interface, so anyone who visit my server website will see pgAdmin panel and can log in.

Current setup:
Apache is configured and running.
PostgreSQL is installed and running.
pgAdmin is installed only.

The only solution I googled out is https://www.pgadmin.org/docs/pgadmin4/4.x/server_deployment.html this one, but there are no paths to mentioned files and I dont know, where should I search them for as I am beginner with those kinds of issues.

What should I do next please? How to configure pgAdmin? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I found (been suggested) **phpPgAdmin** instead of pgAdmin and installed and configured with help of official documentation and youtube video.

Answer (score 0):

Some solutions that come to my mind:

- You could block the port with `ufw` used by pgAdmin when you don't want to access it
- You could have the port blocked with `ufw` and use a reverse proxy in which you add some restrictions, like whitelisted IPs. [Apache reverse proxy](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/reverse_proxy.html), [Whitelisting in apache](https://serverfault.com/a/791756)